# Traveling to Ukraine with a UK Refugee 1951 Travel Document: What You Need to Know

Tags: visas, ukraine

What are the travel requirements for individuals holding a UK Refugee 1951 Travel Document who wish to visit Ukraine?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official Ukrainian site [Entry regime to Ukraine for foreign citizens](https://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entry-and-stay-foreigners-ukraine/entry-regime-ukraine-foreign-citizens) (which is marked as of June 08, 2023):

> If you are the holder of a refugee document (according to the Geneva
> Convention) or a stateless person, you always need a visa to enter.

Note: The above link also lists the visa options for a long list of nationalities.

You can register here for [Ukraine entry and transit visa processing](https://visa.mfa.gov.ua/visa/index).  As per Phoog, you need to select "Refugee" as your citizenship.  This site also states:

> Visa applications can be submitted to the Embassy / Consulate / Visa
> center not earlier than three months before the planned trip to
> Ukraine

Finally, we all know that there there is a war going on.  Ukraine is under martial law, and [this site](https://visitukraine.today) (which I have no idea how official it is) states things like:

> Martial law is in effect in Ukraine and air traffic has been
> suspended, however, the entry and exit of foreign citizens by land is
> allowed. Checkpoints on the border with Poland, Slovakia, Hungary,
> Romania and Moldova are open and safe. Checkpoints with the russia,
> Belarus and Transnistria are closed.

And lists requirements such as:

> - availability of a health insurance policy. Insurance in Ukraine is    mandatory.
> - Visit Ukraine also strongly recommends that you take out medical    insurance covering military risks for the entire stay in Ukraine.
>   This policy guarantees monetary compensation in the event of an
>   accident as a result of passive military risks, terrorist acts,
>   including repatriation of the insured person (or his body, in case of
>   death) from the place of stay to the place of his permanent
>   accommodation. Options such as emergency care, outpatient treatment,
>   hospitalization, etc. are included in health insurance contracts.

I had always had the impression that you couldn't get insurance for a war zone.  It seems that I may be wrong on that.  But I can't imagine that it is cheap (if you *can* get it).

Comment: FYI, it *is* possible to get travel insurance for Ukraine from various European insurance companies. But a normal policy won't cover war-related risks.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko It's the "war" aspect I have no knowledge about.  I've never gone into a war zone by choice (or even accidently)

Comment: You can get a policy for *everything* provided you pay accordingly

Comment: @NicolasFormichella And I'd love to see what a quote for Ukraine actually costs!

Comment: @PeterM Health insurance is mandatory for foreigners in Ukraine, but it doesn't have to cover war-related risks.

Comment: Medical insurance covering military risk: 3€ per day
https://visitukraine.today/products/war-risks-insurance
If you are > 70 y.o., war is more expensive, at 7.8€/day

Comment: @NicolasFormichella After many years of being an employee of a large insurance company, I can tell you that your statement is not true. In many cases, insurance companies simply refuse to cover certain risks, for whatever price.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko If you're in a war zone, and don't have war related risks in your policy and something happens to you, my cynical guess would be that any claims get declined very quickly.

Comment: "You haven't specified your nationality": which is in any event irrelevant for someone traveling with a refugee travel document.  Such a person enters "refugee" on the page you linked to.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. I looked through that drop down list and overlooked "refugee"

Comment: It's easy to miss, what with all the "Republic of" this and thats.  But it's also slightly off-putting that they say "nationality" when they're really asking what travel document you're using.  Some sites I've seen really do overlook stateless people and refugees entirely.

Comment: @PeterM It's worth mentioning that not the entire Ukraine is a war zone. If you break a leg in western Ukraine, it's not a war-related insurance claim.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Russia has the ability and has conducted strikes in many places all over Ukraine.  EG Kyiv has on average 2 air raid alerts *per* day in 2023 from Russian attacks.  The entire country is a war zone.  What you are suggesting is that *statistically* you are unlikely to encounter Russian aggression in parts of the country - but that doesn't mean that it can't happen.  In addition, insurance companies make profits by denying claims.  So be prepared to show that you didn't break your leg because you panicked and fell when you heard an air raid siren go off.

Comment: @PeterM Fair enough, the insurance company might try their luck.